# Intellisense in VBE not fully functioning for objects

Tags: intellisense, vbe

I've seen in online tutorials Intellisense works the magic: while you key in the object name, it auto complete it for you. Why my VBE doesn't? It works on properties and methods, but not objects.

I'm using Office 2010, maybe the feature is not available in early versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intellisense feature has two requirements:

1. **Compileable Code** - Choose menu option `Debug..Compile VBA Project` to compile. If the project isn't compileable, Intellisense can get confused about when and where to present itself.
2. **Strongly typed variables** - Variables and Object Model members must be strongly typed in order for Intellisense to work.

   - None of these variables are strongly typed, so none of them will have Intellisense:

     `Dim sht1, sht2 As Variant, sht3 As Object`

     Whereas, `Dim sht1 As Worksheet` will get Intellisense
   - Some object model members, like `Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` return a `Variant` (because the `Worksheets` method can return a single `Worksheet` or an array of `Worksheets`). In order to get Intellisense, you'll need to explicitly declare a strongly typed variable, and then work with that variable:

     ```
     'Explicitly declare a strongly typed variable
     Dim sht1 As Worksheet
     'Cast the Variant result to a Worksheet
     Set sht1 = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
     With sht1
         'Type a period to invoke Intellisense for the Worksheet object
         Debug.Print .Name
     End With
     ```

     If you're working with members that return types that are defined in another library, like `Excel.Application.VBE`, then you'll need to add a reference to that library (in this example, `VBIDE`) before you can declare an appropriate strongly typed member.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer my question, what you share is VERY useful. Thanks heaps.

Comment: If it's been helpful, feel free to upvote the answer. If you have more details about the object that's not providing Intellisense, perhaps edit your original question with the details, and I might be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

To force Intellisense feature in VBE, simply press Ctrl+Space.